# Spoiler markup for multiple paragraph block

Tags: support

The spoiler markup becomes a mess when the block has multiple paragraphs. I cannot seem to figure out the right way to do it. Here are some things I tried. None of them work. What is the correct way to do this?

**Mark each paragraph individually**

*Markup*

```
>!This is the first paragraph of a spoiler block.

>!This is the second paragraph.
```

*Result*

> !This is the first paragraph of a spoiler block.
>
> !This is the second paragraph.

**Mark each paragraph individually, and also mark the paragraph break**

*Markup*

```
>!This is the first paragraph of a spoiler block.
>!
>!This is the second paragraph.
```

*Result*

> This is the first paragraph of a spoiler block.
>
> This is the second paragraph.

**Mark only the first paragraph, and use < br> tags**

*Markup*

```
>!This is the first paragraph of a spoiler block. <br><br>
This is the second paragraph.
```

*Result*

> !This is the first paragraph of a spoiler block. 
>   This is the second paragraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>! This is the first paragraph of a spoiler block.-- 
>! --
>! This is the second paragraph.
```

> This is the first paragraph of a spoiler block.
>
>  This is the second paragraph.

The -- are there two indicate two spaces (hit the space bar twice then enter to go to the new line).

Anyway, *avoid* making huge spoiler blocks. Put into the spoiler only the relevant bit. We need searchable questions.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the 2 spaces thing of markdown. :)

Comment: @Deidara-senpai You're welcome!